# Dired+. Mouse click - open folder in the same window

Tags: dired

When I open a folder by pressing "Enter" it will open in the same window:

[image]

[image]

This behavior is OK and basically what I expect.

But when I try to open a folder by clicking with the left mouse button the folder will open in another window:

[image]

I would like to open the folder in the same window no matter if I use the keyboard or click with the mouse.

How I can do this with Emacs 25.1, and Dired+, in Windows 10?

Answer (score 10):

If you're using Emacs 26 or later (unlike what is specified in the question...), you can just use:

```
(define-key dired-mode-map [mouse-2] 'dired-mouse-find-file)
```

(The default binding is `dired-mouse-find-file-other-window`.)

If you're using Emacs 24 or 25, you'll need to copy the definition of the function, from the [Emacs sources](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/2260e48d2eeaa9ea2b9c17389cc25d00f85c414c/lisp/dired.el#L2296) (or from this answer — I've copied the definition below, for completeness) into you `init.el`. I've tested with Emacs 24.5, and it works.

#### Definition of `dired-mouse-find-file`

I've taken the function from [here](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/2260e48d2eeaa9ea2b9c17389cc25d00f85c414c/lisp/dired.el#L2296) and wrapped it in a check for the version of Emacs, so that if you upgrade to a later Emacs and the definition of the function changes, the stale definition doesn't override the new one.

> ```el
> (when (< emacs-major-version 26)
>   (defun dired-mouse-find-file (event &optional find-file-func find-dir-func)
>     "In Dired, visit the file or directory name you click on.
> The optional arguments FIND-FILE-FUNC and FIND-DIR-FUNC specify
> functions to visit the file and directory, respectively.  If
> omitted or nil, these arguments default to `find-file' and `dired',
> respectively."
>     (interactive "e")
>     (or find-file-func (setq find-file-func 'find-file))
>     (or find-dir-func (setq find-dir-func 'dired))
>     (let (window pos file)
>       (save-excursion
>         (setq window (posn-window (event-end event))
>               pos (posn-point (event-end event)))
>         (if (not (windowp window))
>             (error "No file chosen"))
>         (set-buffer (window-buffer window))
>         (goto-char pos)
>         (setq file (dired-get-file-for-visit)))
>       (if (file-directory-p file)
>           (or (and (cdr dired-subdir-alist)
>                    (dired-goto-subdir file))
>               (progn
>                 (select-window window)
>                 (funcall find-dir-func file)))
>         (select-window window)
>         (funcall find-file-func (file-name-sans-versions file t))))))
> ```

(For license purposes, the code is under GPLv3+, not under CC BY-SA!)

#### Explanation

The reason why we're binding `mouse-2` rather than `mouse-1`, even to specify the action taken when you click on the link with the left mouse button (`mouse-1`) is slightly complicated.

Dired specifies (via `dired-insert-set-properties`) that in the dired buffer, the name of the file or folder (as opposed to the displayed permissions, name of the owner and other metadata) is a link. In the dired-mode-map, the "key sequence" `[follow-link]` is bound to `mouse-face`. This means that when you left-click on the link (*but not elsewhere*), emacs "translates" your left-click to a middle-click (`mouse-2`). (For more details, [see the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Clickable-Text.html).)

Consequently, if you want to specify what happens when you left-click on the link, but not elsewhere, you slightly perversely have to change the binding of `mouse-2`. You could directly bind to `mouse-1` with `(define-key dired-mode-map [mouse-1] 'dired-mouse-find-file)`, but that would mean that left-clicking anywhere in the buffer (including in the metadata columns) would cause the corresponding file or directory to be opened.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I proceed as you shown, but I get the error `command-execute: Wrong type argument: commandp, dired-mouse-find-file` when trying to use it. What could that be? Thanks!

Comment: Oops, that's (probably) my fault. The function `dired-mouse-find-file` was added in Emacs 26, so if you're using a version of Emacs older than that, it won't be present. You'll need to manually add the definition of the function, e.g. from [here](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/2260e48d2eeaa9ea2b9c17389cc25d00f85c414c/lisp/dired.el#L2296). I'll edit the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's indeed very useful

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problem! (I hope it works now.)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't check it out right now, but I will do so once I'm able to and I will let you know!

Comment: Thank you.  I don't know who made this design decision and when, but this is how I think it should be!